# Cannot integrate change using perforce

Tags: perforce

I am trying to integrate a change list from one branch of code to another branch.For this I do

```
1)p4 integ old_branch@cl,cl new_branch 
2)p4 resolve -am
3)p4 change.
```

Now when I am doing the last part(p4 change ) I see this error :-

> The document “tmp.BLAH BLAH” could not be opened. You don’t have
>   permission.

Has anyone seen this before and can help me correct this?I do have the config file under the branch's root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using P4V with Perforce when I had to use it. Drastically helped me with merges considering P4 is not quite like using SVN or Git.

Also I think that if the file can be removed from your filesystem you can revert to the latest from the repository if in fact it is a file from the repository. Then you can retry your merge.

I know in other merge programs the tmp files are generated during the conflict resolution process so you may be facing a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! but I found out the reason to be that I had not set up the default editor ($EDITOR  variable) and that was causing issues.